# Функция проверяющая пароль на валидность

Tags: javascript, валидация, password

Пытаюсь написать функцию валидация пароля. Функция должна проверять длину пароля. Если пароль не введен, выдавать ошибку с надписью "Поле обязательно для заполнения" и подсвечивать окно красным. Если введеный пароль меньше 8 символов, то должна появляться ошибка с надписью "Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов". Если соответствует условиям, то окно становится зеленого цвета.
Попыталась сделать по аналогии с валидацией e-mail. Но функция не работает. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку?

```js
'use strict'

const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;
const passCheck = (/^(?=.*\d).{8,15}$/).length;

const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const errorIsOn = document.querySelector('#error');
const preheader = document.querySelector('#preheader');
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const errorpass = document.querySelector('#errorpass');
const errorpass2 = document.querySelector('#errorpass2');



function isEmailValid(value) {
  return emailChecker.test(value);
}

function onInput() {
  if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';

  } else {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorIsOn.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
  }
}

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', onInput);

function isPasswordValid(value) {
  return passChecker.test(value);
}

function passValidation() {
  if (isPasswordValid(password.value.length <= 8)) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
  } else if (isPasswordValid(password.value.length === 0)) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    password.style.borderColor = 'green';
  }
}

password.addEventListener('keyup', passValidation);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  max-height: 769px;
  background-color: #1B2473;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .body {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 412px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 82px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    width: 728px;
    height: 697px;
  }
}

.form__preheader {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__preheader {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.form__header {
  width: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__header {
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.form__field {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__field {
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
  }
}

.form__error {
  display: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #CB2424;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.form__star {
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__box {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.form__text {
  width: 278px;
  height: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__text {
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.form__send {
  width: 180px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__send {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form" id='form'>

    <h1 class="form__header">Вход</h1>
    <p class="form__preheader" id='preheader'>E-mail</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail">
    <p class="form__error" id='error'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class="form__preheader">Пароль</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
    <p class="form__error" id='errorpass'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class="form__error" id='errorpass2'>Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов</p>

    <div class="form__pc">
      <input class="form__box" type="checkbox" id="box">
      <label for="box" class="form__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="form__send" id='btn'>
            Войти
    </button>
    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А зачем здесь `(/^(?=.*\d).{8,15}$/).length` собственно `length`? И переменная у Вас называется не `passChecker`, а `passCheck`

Comment: @Simon каюсь, недоглядела. Но поправила и все равно функция не работает.

Comment: Ну у Вас там каша в функции `passValidation`.  Зачем Вам в принципе регулярка присвоенная переменной `passCheck`, если Вы проверяете только длинну пароля? К тому же функция `isPasswordValid()` принимает значение поля, а не результат сравнения по типу: `password.value.length === 0`. Если нужна проверка только на длинну, то в if оставьте `password.value.length <= 8`, а в else if `password.value.length === 0`. И не мешало бы их поменять местами, так как если `password.value.length === 0`, то условие `password.value.length <= 8` тоже будет истинно и второе условие не сработает.

Comment: @Simon да уж) и в голове каша) Большое спасибо, все поправила и получилось!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
'use strict'

const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;
const passCheck = (/^(?=.*\d).{8,15}$/).length;

const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const errorIsOn = document.querySelector('#error');
const preheader = document.querySelector('#preheader');
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const errorpass = document.querySelector('#errorpass');
const errorpass2 = document.querySelector('#errorpass2');
const errorpass3 = document.querySelector('#errorpass3');



function isEmailValid(value) {
    return emailChecker.test(value);
}

function onInput() {
    if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
        emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';

    } else {
        emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
        errorIsOn.style.display = 'initial';
        preheader.style.color = 'red';
    }
}

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', onInput);

// function isPasswordValid(value) {
//     return passChecker.test(value);
// }

function setPasswordError(elem) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
    if (elem) elem.style.display = 'initial';
}

function resetError() {
    errorpass.style.display = 'none';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'none';
}

function passValidation(event) {
    if (!event.target.value.trim()) {
        resetError()
        setPasswordError(errorpass);
    } else if (event.target.value.length < 8) {
        resetError()
        setPasswordError(errorpass2);
    } else if (event.target.value.search(/[a-z][0-9]/) == -1) {
        resetError()
        setPasswordError(errorpass3);
    } else {
        password.style.borderColor = 'green';
        resetError()
    }
    // if (isPasswordValid(password.value.length <= 8)) {
    //     password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    //     
    //     preheader.style.color = 'red';
    // } else if (isPasswordValid(password.value.length === 0)) {
    //     password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    //     errorpass2.style.display = 'initial';
    //     preheader.style.color = 'red';
    // } else {
    //     password.style.borderColor = 'green';
    // }
}

password.addEventListener('keyup', passValidation);
```

```css
body {
    max-width: 1440px;
    max-height: 769px;
    background-color: #1B2473;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .body {
        max-width: 768px;
    }
}

.form {
    width: 600px;
    height: 412px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 82px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .form {
        width: 728px;
        height: 697px;
    }
}

.form__preheader {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #787878;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form__preheader {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}

.form__header {
    width: 115px;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #787878;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form__header {
        width: 138px;
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}

.form__field {
    width: 509px;
    height: 49px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form__field {
        width: 638px;
        height: 49px;
    }
}

.form__error {
    display: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #CB2424;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.form__star {
    width: 7px;
    height: 12px;
    color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form__box {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
}

.form__text {
    width: 278px;
    height: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #787878;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form__text {
        width: 358px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.form__send {
    width: 180px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: #1A226B;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form__send {
        width: 220px;
        height: 80px;
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form class="form" id='form'>

        <h1 class="form__header">Вход</h1>
        <p class="form__preheader" id='preheader'>E-mail</p>
        <input class="form__field" type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail">
        <p class="form__error" id='error'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
        <p class="form__preheader">Пароль</p>
        <input class="form__field" type="text" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
        <p class="form__error" id='errorpass'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
        <p class="form__error" id='errorpass2'>Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов</p>
        <p class="form__error" id="errorpass3">Пароль должен содержать букву и цифру</p>

        <div class="form__pc">
            <input class="form__box" type="checkbox" id="box">
            <label for="box" class="form__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
        </label>
        </div>

        <button class="form__send" id='btn'>
            Войти
    </button>
        <script src="./src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```